# How to path to a directory provided with the Python package using configuration variables?

Tags: python

I have a Python package that needs to occasionally download and use some files from a repository. To make these files visible to the package and to the user, I have used the approach from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43941592/9167166) answer to create a `config`  module that stores the paths to directories where the data can be downloaded and subsequently found. For example,

**config.py**

```
class ConfigVars:
    __config = {
        "DATA_DIR": "./data",    # <--- Where data is stored
    }

    @staticmethod
    def get(name):
        return ConfigVars.__config[name]

    @staticmethod
    def set(name, value):
        ConfigVars.__config[name] = value
```

The obvious issue with this approach is that `DATA_DIR` is defined relative to the place of execution, so it would need to be made in every directory where it is called. For our purpose the data is read-only, so I'd like for it to be present in one place. For example, I have the following project structure,

```
├── data
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── package
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   ├── ...
```

I'd like to know the path to the `data` folder.

Of course, one possibility is to use relative paths with respect to `__file__` (credit to this [blog post](https://medium.com/@dataproducts/python-the-pythonic-way-to-handle-file-directories-for-your-data-project-6b19417463ad)). For example, I can write the following in `config.py`

```
__config = {"DATA_DIR": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../data") }
```

But this will only work in editable installs and not in virtual environments. Is there a better, perhaps more obvious, way to specify directory paths that will work in general irrespective of where and how the package is installed? Should I structure the project differently?

> **Note:** I am aware of other threads discussing ways to pass config variables. This post isn't about how to specify config variables but about the issues when using relative and absolute directory paths as config variables, irrespective of how these are defined.

Comment: this config class seems over-engineered. Why not just use a dictionary?

Comment: Having a class helps to control access rather than having these variables be public and mutable. Not really necessary if it isn't necessary. Either way, even when using a dictionary, the issue is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the best way to achieve this is by **not** packaging the `data` directory and leaving it for the user to decide if they would want to change the location (default - current directory). The user can change this after import like so

```py
from package import config
config.ConfigVars.set("DATA_DIR", "./someotherdir")
```

Or if using dictionaries for config variables -

```py
from package import config
config.ConfigVars["DATA_DIR"] = "./someotherdir"
```

This works if you don't need to include data with the package.

If you have to include data with your package, I would suggest reading the `setuptools` [documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) that has examples for different package structures. In particular, the docs say that using `__file__` to get the path to data files is a hack that is not compatible with `.egg`, and to use `importlib.resources` for this purpose.

I'll leave this question open in case there are other ideas.