# Centralizing configuration in python

Tags: python

Currently my configuration options (constants / variables) are a bit fragmented, I have most of them in config.py but some are in the myfile.py at the top.

```
/utilities/myfile.py
/config.py
```

An example of what you might find in my myfile.py is:

```
TEMP_DIR = '/tmp'
```

If I wanted to move this definition from my myfile.py into my config.py but still use it in my myfile.py, how do I go about it?

I am new to python but I assume it is something along the lines of this at the top of myfile.py

```
from config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**variant 1**

```
from config import *
```

this polutes the whole namespace in myfile.py

**variant 2**

```
from config import foo, bar, baz
```

Ever value used in myfile.py have to be mentioned.

**variant 3**

```
import config
...
x = config.foo
```

every value need to refer to config.

Your choice, but i prefer variant 3. To *see* config.py in myfile.py, you either have to edit your *PYTHONPATH* or use a relative import:

```
from ... import config
```

Comment: I feel that this is important to note because many python users fail to mention this to new python users: if you use the code `import config`, then you need to add on the module when calling an object within it, like so: `x = config.foo` if you use `from config import *`, however, you do _NOT_ need to put the module before the object: `x = foo`. I forget why this is, but it will save you a lot of time and confusion if you remember this when using python.

Answer (score 0):

In `myfile.py` you could put

```
import config
```

and access `TEMP_DIR` with

```
config.TEMP_DIR
```

provided the directory containing `config.py` is in your [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use `execfile`. This will make it easier to use different configuration files (for instance specify the configuration file to use on the command line).

Example:

```
# myconfig.py
TEMP_DIR = "/tmp/"

# myotherconfig.py
TEMP_DIR = "/tmp/foo"

# program.py (the main program)
import sys
config = {}
execfile(sys.argv[1], config)
print config["TEMP_DIR"]
```

Invoking the program:

```
$ python program.py myconfig.py
/tmp/
$ python program.py myotherconfig.py
/tmp/foo
```

Related: [Python configuration file: Any file format recommendation? INI format still appropriate? Seems quite old school](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225954/python-configuration-file-any-file-format-recommendation-ini-format-still-appr/8226090#8226090)

Comment: 4 possible ways to go ... remember zen of python? "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." ;)

Comment: You are right. We should all use http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html :-)

Comment: I must confess I am norwegian.