# Python: NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, execfile

In my `main()` function I open a config file:

```
cfg = {}
execfile("config.conf", cfg)
```

config.conf looks like this:

```
x = 10
```

Later on, I use `cfg[x]`, which gives me `NameError: global name 'x' is not defined`.
I took the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8226090/2789162), how I use it, looks correctly to me.

Why do I get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked question, the values are accessed with strings matching the identifier names:

```
print config["value1"]
```

Likewise, you should use a string.

```
cfg["x"]
```

Example:

```
cfg = {}
exec("x=23", cfg)
print cfg["x"]
```

Result:

```
23
```

Comment: For completeness, `execfile('config.conf')` (with no second argument) would indeed set the value of `x` to 10, as `execfile` would use the global namespace instead of `cfg`.