# Python3 import variables from myfile.conf

Tags: variables, python-3.x, import

I have a python program 'gametree.py', I want to predefine some variables in 'gametree.conf' and import them into my python program.

I can import them fine if I name it anything.py but I don't want to name it *.py.  It's a config file, I want to match it to the python program name with a .conf extension.

gametree.py & gametree.conf

Possible?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4152986/2833032) might be what you're looking for. You can access the name of a script using the `__file__` variable.

Comment: I don't see how that works.  I want to use the command 'import gametree.conf'... which doesn't work. 'import anything.py' would work but that's not what I want. :-)

Comment: Don't use `import`; Use `open` and read the file. Use something like JSON to save the config data.

Comment: I tried playing with 'open' first. It seems much more difficult to read individual variables. I have to parse it and then the data that is numeric (some strings) I have to convert to integers.  It's a lot more work to use open than to just read in the variables.  I appreciate the offer and you're right but my question stands.  Is there any way to import a file that does NOT end with the extension .py?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225954/python-configuration-file-any-file-format-recommendation-ini-format-still-appr/8226090#8226090

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want the configparser module

this should get you going:

`configexample.py`

```
import configparser
# note that this is for python3. Some changes need to be made for python2

# create parser object and read config file
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('myconfig.cfg')

# loop through. Here for instructional purposes we print, but you can 
# assign etc instead.
for section in config.sections():
    print(section)
    for option in config.options(section):
        text = '{} {}'.format(option, config.get(section,option))
        print(text)
```

￼The section in the code extracts the contents of the brackets [].  Here is an example configuration file `myconfig.cfg`

```
[auth]
username= Petra
password= topsecret
[database]
server= 192.168.1.34
port= 143
file='thatfile.dat'
[Location]
language = English
timezone = UTC
```

For more details have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/configparser.html).

Addendum: Incase you are interested you can also use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/json.html#module-json)  and [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/shlex.html#module-shlex) modules too.