# using a config.py as a configuration file for a Python application

Tags: python

There are multiple posts discussing whether this is recommended, but lets suppose you want to do a `config.py` for your python app. Is there any difference between the two (similar to me) approaches below:

- 1). make the module as an ini file and then parse it with `exec(Path())`

Like the following example, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8226090/5431734):

```
## config.py ##

value1 = 32
value2 = "A string value"

value3 = ["lists", "are", "handy"]
value4 = {"and": "so", "are": "dictionaries"}
```

and then

```
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = {}
    exec(Path("config.py").read_text(encoding="utf8"), {}, config)
    
    print config["value1"]
    print config["value4"]
```

- 2). write a module with just a dictionary with the settings and then import the module:

Hence:

```
## config.py ##

DEFAULT = {
    value1: 32,
    value2: "A string value",

    value3: ["lists", "are", "handy"],
    value4 : {"and": "so", "are": "dictionaries"},
}
```

and then

```
import config.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cfg = config.DEFAULT
    
    print cfg["value1"]
    print cfg["value4"]
```

Comment: The second one is surely better than simply executing a file with no input control over it... But why not just have a `config.ini` and read with the built-in [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do both these approaches but as Tomerikoo explain, there is both an advantage and disadvantage in your config being a code:

Advantage: It is elegant (especially your second way) and you can easily execute some dynamical setting or similar because your config is code.

Disadvantage: If you don't have control over the config, someone can execute the code he is not supposed to execute. Also things can go more bad for this reason.

[`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) is the preferred way how to do this unless your config is more of a script than just a plain key-value based config.