# How to save application settings in a config file?

Tags: python, settings, app-config, ini

I am developing a program that has a settings window in which I can change various parameters for my program. What is the best way to read/save them in some kind of config file? I know that some software and games use `.ini` files or similar system. How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Best way is probably xml.

Comment: @enginefree, that's literally never true.

Comment: [configparser](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/configparser.html) is simple and implemented right there in the standard library.

Comment: You could use python as the language for your settings file.

Comment: @ExP Although that always adds the possibility of malicious config files - whether or not it's a good idea varies greatly depending on the situation.

Comment: Quite similar to this question which has some very informative answwers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055042/whats-the-best-practice-using-a-settings-file-in-python?rq=1

Comment: An alternative to `ConfigParser` would be to use the [Voidspace](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/) Python module named [ConfigObj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#configobj) by Michael Foord. See the [**The Advantages of ConfigObj**](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/configobj.shtml#the-advantages-of-configobj) section of an article he wrote titled [**_An Introduction to ConfigObj_**](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/configobj.shtml) as to why you might want to do this.

Comment: Also note the (different) accepted answer—mine—to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696281/how-to-store-application-settings-across-modules) that was marked as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Python standard library includes the [`ConfigParser` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html), which handles ini-style configuration files for you. It's more than adequate for most uses.

Comment: Note that in 3.x, it's been renamed [`configparser`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/configparser.html).

Answer (score 9):

Another popular option for configuration files is JSON - it's a simple notation which has good support from a wide range of languages.

Python has [the `json` module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html#module-json) in the standard library, which makes it very easy.

Answer (score 3):

Since you introduced the term config file in your question, the previous answers concentrated on means for creating plain text files, which also could be manipulated using a standard text editor. Depending on the sort of settings to store this might not be desired, since it requires strict plausibility checks after reading back the config file at the very least. So I add the proposal of the [shelves](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module which is a straight-forward way to make information persistent in files.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the vast majority of cases, binary config files are considered a bad idea - you make it much harder for the end user to work with them.