# True way to use setting in python project

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, variables, config

I have python project in 1 file. There is 5 classes in file. The classes uses global variables, which stores configs of all project.

I want refactoring my project, and have write out all variables in cfg file. Then i parse the file with ConfigObj python parser.

Now, how can i dispose of global variables in the classes in "true python way"?
Does i need use something like programming pattern? Or, maybe, place all variables in one class, which named "setting", and use it everywhere?

Example of my code:

```
global_var_1 = 1
global_var_2 = 2
global_var_3 = 3
global_var_4 = 4
global_var_5 = 5
global_var_6 = 6

class First():
    def method1():
        global global_var_1, global_var_3
        pass #some code here

    def method2():
        global global_var_1, global_var_6
        pass #some code here

    def method3():
        global global_var_2, global_var_3
        pass #some code here
    #........

class Second():
    def method1():
        global global_var_5
        pass #some code here

    def method2():
        global global_var_4, global_var_6
        pass #some code here

    def method3():
        global global_var_1, global_var_3
        pass #some code here
    #.........
#And some other classes...

global_var_3 = 4
#and some other "global" code
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15992387/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16696281/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5055042/3001761, ...