# python configuration at compile time

Tags: python, python-2.7

As of now we have a file `conf.py` which stores most of our configuration variables for the service. We have code similar to this:

```
environment = 'dev' # could be dev, local, staging, production
configa = 'something'
configb = 'something else'

if environment = 'dev':
    configa = 'something dev'

elif environment = 'local':
    configa = 'something local'
```

Is this the right way to manage configuration file in a python project? Are these configuration loaded into variables at compile time (while creating pyc files), or are the if conditions checked every time the conf is imported in a python script or is it every time a configuration variable is accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All code runs at import time. But since you are unlikely to import your application again and again while it's running you can ignore the (minimal) overhead.

Answer (score 2):

This is subjective but there is a good discussion in this post:
[What's the best practice using a settings file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055042/whats-the-best-practice-using-a-settings-file-in-python)

With your method, it will be treated the same way as any other python script, i.e. on import.  If you wanted it updated on access/or without restarting the service it is best to use an external/non-python config file (e.g. json, .ini) and set up functionality to refresh the file.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a file, example `settings.py`,
add the path to the module where the file to the system.
Example:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Аfter anywhere you can import the file and to obtain from any setting:

```
import settings

env = settings.environment
```

Similarly, many working frameworks.