# Is there a way to save the variable value in python In case of power failure on the raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Is there a way to save the variable value in python In case of power failure so when i run the program again it does not start from initial value but the value which was saved last.In the below code i am counting the number of times a button is pressed so can i save the value of age and start counting from the saved value insted of starting from 15.

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import time
 age=15                   //initialize for debugging
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
 GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN,GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

 def led(channel):                     //funtion for increnment age
     global age
     age=(age+1)
     print(age)
```

## PIN 7 AND 3.3V

## normally 0 when connected 1

```
 GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.RISING, callback=led, bouncetime=1000 )
 print(age)
 try:
     while(True):
            time.sleep(1)
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
           GPIO.cleanup()
           print (age)
           print ("Exiting")
```

Comment: Save it to a file every minute in a function with multiprocessing and time modules

Comment: can you provide an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best practice using a settings file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055042/whats-the-best-practice-using-a-settings-file-in-python)

Comment: Have a look at how to read/write config files in YAML, JSON, INI etc formats...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

open a terminal and type the following to create an file named as 'led.txt' :

```
>>>import pickle    
>>>s={'age':None}    
>>>with open('led.txt','w') as f:
...        f.write(pickle.dumps(s))
```

Then proceed with you code

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import time
 import pickle

 led_age={'age':None}  # initialise as dictionary

 with open('led.txt') as f: # open file in read mode  
   led_age = pickle.loads(f.read())  #initialize for debugging

 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
 GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN,GPIO.PUD_DOWN)


 def led(channel): 
     global led_age       

     led_age['age'] += 1     # increment value
     with open('led.txt','w') as f:    # again open the file in write mode
       f.write(pickle.dumps(led_age))  #pickle the dictionary and write back to the file

     print(led_age)
```

instead of an int variable I have used a dictionary.

the function `led` does the following:

1. open the file 'led.txt' in readonly mode(default mode) and load the
   dictionary
2. Increment the 'age'
3. Again open the file 'led.txt' but in write mode and write back the
   updated dictionary

`pickle.dumps` serializes the dictionary to strings, and `pickle.loads` does the deserialization

Each time the function **led** is called this updation will be carried out automatically and the `led.txt` file will be updated.

**Note** : An alternative to pickle can be JSON which is compatible with other languages

Comment: JSON is a good choice for writing data structures as well. It's standardized, and is cross-language.

Comment: @stevieb thank you for the mention, I forgot about cross-platform compatibility

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is via writing and writing to a file.  You can read from the file the program state when starting the program, and modify the file as the variable state changes.

For saving more complex data structures, the [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module exists.  This allows objects to be serialized.

Comment: JSON is a highly useful and standardized way to store data beyond a simple integer or string as well, and it's also cross-platform and cross-language.