# write to configuration fmodule

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using the code as menstioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055042/whats-the-best-practice-using-a-settings-file-in-python)

```
truck = dict(
    color = 'blue',
    brand = 'ford',
)
city = 'new york'
cabriolet = dict(
    color = 'black',
    engine = dict(
        cylinders = 8,
        placement = 'mid',
    ),
    doors = 2,
)
```

and using it like this

```
import config
print(config.truck['color'])
```

How do I write to the config, I tried the code below but it does not work.

```
config.truck['color'] = "yellow"
```

Comment: Why do you think that it does not work?

Comment: @mkrieger1 because i open the file and its not been weritten to

Comment: You should have followed one of the other answers from the linked question, not that one.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the reason the config is not being written to is that importing a python file creates an instance of the module - it is not directly accessing the file. When you change the variables in the module, it is only changing the variables in your instance of the module, stored in your RAM.

Secondly, on the matter of saving your variables, try something like this:

```
import json

class Config:
    def __init__(self, truck, city, cabriolet): #add more variables to this constructor if required
        self.truck=truck
        self.city=city
        self.cabriolet=cabriolet
    def Save(self):
        configFile=open("config.cfg","w+") #saves the config data to a .cfg file, although any extension will work
        configFile.write(json.dumps(self.__dict__)) #saves the contents of the config object
        configFile.close()
    def Load(self):
        configFile=open("config.cfg","r")
        self.__dict__=json.loads(configFile.read()) #loads the config object from the contents of the text file
        configFile.close()

#this is just setting up the contents that we will put into the config
truck=dict(color='blue',brand='ford')
city='new york'
cabriolet=dict(color='black', engine=dict(cylinders=8,placement='mid'), doors=2)

config=Config(truck,city,cabriolet) #this stores all your config data

config.truck["color"]="brown" #how to set the data
#these are examples of how you access the data
print("Color of truck: "+config.truck["color"])
print("Name of city: "+config.city)
print("Doors on cabriolet: "+str(config.cabriolet["doors"]))
config.Save() #saves your changes to the config data

config.Load() #later on you can load the variables
```